# delete the autowire from controller and replace it with normal initialization

Tags: java, annotations, javabeans

My current codes contain @autowired but I would like to remove it and then initialize it with code. Please vote down my questions if you found it hard to understand but PLEASE at least comment so that I can re-edit as I am new to this annotation stuff and still getting my hands wet with it.

Below shows my code and from what I could understand about autowired is that it takes the values from class "Test" and wire the values to testing. What about if I remove this @autowired from the code? How can I still make it executable? I mean, if I remove the @autowired, how can I still initialized the values in this same line instead of using the wiring annotation? - Reason I wanted to try this is to see my understanding and at the same time see more different examples to improve my understranding

```
 @Autowired
  @Qualifier("testing")
  Test testing;
```

I dont have expected results because I just want to understand the annotations and see whether my understanding is correct.

Comment: Are you using Spring?

Comment: Yes, I am using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three ways to inject an autowired dependency (using spring) into a bean:

1. Autowiring the field itself

   ```
   @Autowired
   private Test test;

   @Autowired
   private SomethingService somethingService;
   ```
2. Autowiring a setter

   ```
   private Test test;
   private SomethingService somethingService;

   @Autowired
   public void setTest(Test test) {
       this.test = test;
   }

   @Autowired
   public void setSomethingService(SomethingService somethingService) {
       this.somethingService = somethingService;
   }
   ```
3. Autowiring the constructor (which doesn't need an annotation):

   ```
   public class Something {

       private Test test;
       private SomethingService somethingService;

       public Something(Test test, SomethingService somethingService) {
           this.test = test;
           this.somethingService = somethingService;
       }

       ...
   }
   ```

A benefit of using the third approach is that when you construct an instance of the class for testing, you can pass in any implementations you want for the dependencies.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Now this cleared my confuse. I have read many other sites for tutorials and so their explanation and when it comes to many different types of injection, I kind of lost. Now with this, I think I understand how it works. thank you again.

Comment: Just would like to confirm, if I have 3 properties with @ injection. Then I delete all these three @ injection. I should use third  approach for every each properties, right? So I will have 3 initialization for these 3 properties separately?

Comment: Edited to show how more than one dependency is handled.